# Existence of solution to gradient flow on Riemannian manifold

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, dynamical-systems

I found the following theorem in Helmke & Moore, *Optimization and Dynamical Systems* (Appendix C.12):

"Let Φ : M → R be a smooth function on a Riemannian manifold with compact sublevel sets, i.e. for all c ∈ R the sublevel set {x ∈ M | Φ(x) ≤ c} is a (possibly empty) compact subset of M. Then every solution x (t) ∈ M of the gradient flow on M exists for all t ≥ 0."

They do not leave any references. **I am looking for a version of this theorem that would relax smoothness ($C^\infty$) to continuously differentiable, along with whatever other assumptions that may be necessary.**

I have found such theorems elsewhere, but they embed $\Phi$ in a Hilbert space (and require it to be convex), which is something that I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I presume you mean the ODE system
\begin{equation}
\tag{$*$}
\dot{x} = {\color{red}-} {\nabla}\Phi(x).
\end{equation}

Assume that $\Phi \colon M \to \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^2$ function having compact sublevel sets. Fix $x_0 \in M$, and put $c := \Phi(x_0)$.  Let $x \colon [0, \tau_{\mathrm{max}}) \to M$ be the maximally defined (to the right) solution of ($*$) satisfying the initial condition $x(0) = x_0$. We have $\Phi(x(t)) \le c$, that is, $\{\, x(t) | t \in [0, \tau_{\mathrm{max}})\, \} \subset \{\, \xi \in M | \Phi(\xi) \le c \,\}$.  As the latter is compact, the standard extension theorem for ODE systems (see, e.g., Corollary 2.15 on pp. 52-53 in Teschl's [Ordinary Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-ode/ode.pdf)) gives $\tau_{\mathrm{max}} = \infty$.

I think that the smoothness assumption on $\Phi$ can be relaxed to $C^1$, but then the vector field $-\nabla\Phi$ is continuous only, and there can be difficulties with the uniqueness of solutions.

Comment: Thanks, but the reference you provide consider systems that evolve on subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Anyhow, I found an intrinsic treatment that of the question in Section 6.4 of Jost "Riemannian geometry and geometric analysis". It also assumes that $\Phi$ is $C^2$. I have reconsidered my needs and decided that $C^2$ will do :)